# minimum value of a+d

Tags: number-theory

If the mean of a,b,c,d is 100 and a < b < c < d, a,b,c,d are all integers. What's the minimum value of a + d?

Here 's what I think: for a given d, we should let b and c be as great as possible to minimize a. So take c=d-1 and b=d-2. Then a=403-3d. So a+d=403-2d. And we get that there is no minimum value as d could be arbitrarily large. But if a, b,c and d are all positive, then there will be a minimum value when d=134. I'm not sure if fixing d in the first place works or not or if the reasoning is rigorous. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we want to minimize $a+d$ , we want to maximize the parameter $b+c$.

$$\frac{a+b+c+d}4 = 100 \implies a+b+c+d = 400$$

Setting $c= d-1$ and $b= d-2$ and $a=1 \text { (Since a should be minimized )}$

$$ \begin{align} 1+d-2+d-1+d & = 400 \\ 
 3d -2 & = 400 \\ 
d = \frac{402}{3} \implies \boxed{\color{red}{d = 134}}\end{align}$$

And minimum possible value $a+d$ is $135$

Comment: Hi thank you! You are assuming all a, b, c and d are positive, right?

Comment: @stevengerrard That's what you have asked for.

Comment: thank you. So if we remove that requirement, that would be no minimum value, is it correct？